# How can I tell if an Azure IoT Consumer Group is active?

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub

I have inherited a couple of Azure IoT Hubs which have a number of Consumer Groups defined on them and am trying to map out the processing that is taking place.  How can I tell if an Azure IoT Consumer Group is being used or is safe to remove?

Answer (score 4):

If a consumer group is active, it creates a "Lease" on a Eventhub partition to read the messages. (Note: by default the messages of IotHub are published through an endpoint which is compatible to an EventHub).

The information on "Leases" are stored in an Azure BlobContainer which has to be defined when creating the IotHub.  The default name of the BlobContainer is "azure-webjobs-eventhub".

For the build in endpoint of an IotHub the blob names should look like this:

```
<EventHubEndpoint>.servicebus.windows.net/<IotHubName>/<ConsumerGroupName>/<PartitionId>
```

For additional EventHubs connected to the IotHub the blob names probably look like this:

```
<EventHubName>.servicebus.windows.net/<EventHubEntityName>/<ConsumerGroupName>/<PartitionId>
```

You can look at the BlobProperties "LastModified" and "Status" and "LeaseState" to determine whether the ConsumerGroup is active or not.

Comment: Thank you. That's very helpful information.  I can see some lease containers within some of my storage accounts. The tell-tale signs are a folder within the container  that has the same name as the consumer group within which are a set of files, one for each partition (e.g. 0,1,2,3 for default of 4 partitions). However the container name appears to be user-defined and is definitely not defined at Iot Hub creation time (I created a new hub to check this out). I have found multiple lease container for the same consumer group so I don't think this is a reliable way to determine activity.

Comment: It is possible to consumer events from the same consumer group using different storage containers or accounts for their lease.  I have tried this.  However, you cannot run two consumers on the same consumer group simultaneously, one will have a higher lease Epoch and will trump the other.  I think this may give a way to determine activity - register a consumer on the consumer group but don't checkpoint and if you get a lease Epoch exception then another consumer is active.  I will try this out and update here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Azure IoT Hub Toolkit](https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode-azure-iot-toolkit) - go to Settings->Extensions->Azure IoT Hub Toolkit and define the consumer group you would like to read D2C messages.

[image: Settings->Extensions->Azure IoT Hub Toolkit]

You can then Start Monitoring D2C messages and see if the Consumer Group is active or not.

[image: Start Monitoring D2C messages]
[image: $Default Consumer Group]

Comment: This does not solve the problem!  All this does is make VS Code use this consumer group for monitoring messages.  There can still be other consumers that have the same consumer group defined.  If VS Code uses the same consumer group as someone else, each message will only be received by one of the two. Once a message has been received, it cannot be received again by someone else with the same consumerGroup.

Comment: I agree with you that this will just be monitoring messages and check current activity. You are also true that a message cannot be received by two consumers - by experience I believe if a consumer group is in use, you will see an error when trying to listen for messages as well. I am leaving my answer here as an alternative method and make people more aware that you can define what consumer group you want to listen for messages when using Azure IoT Hub Toolkit :)! Will vote for your answer. Thanks!